# Django rest framework регистрация пользователя

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Как сделать сериалайзер для регистрации поьзователя с полем для подтверждения пароля.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})
password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})

class Meta:
    model = ExtUser
    fields = ('email', 'name', 'password', 'password2')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, },
                    'password2': {'write_only': True, },
                    }

def validate(self, attrs):
    data = super(UserSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
    if data['password'] != data['password2']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Password mismatch')
    del data['password2']
    return data

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = ExtUser(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        name=validated_data['name'],
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user

def update(self, user, validated_data):
    user.name = validated_data['name']
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

в тестах выдает такую ошибку

> AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for
>   field `password2` on serializer `UserSerializer`. The serializer field
>   might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
>   `ExtUser` instance. Original exception text was: 'ExtUser' object has
>   no attribute 'password2'.

Answer (score 1):

Надо убрать поля `password` и `password2` из `Meta.fields`. Вы используете `ModelSerializer`, который сопоставляет поля модели со тем, что указано в `Meta.fields`. Можно убрать `extra_kwargs`, потому что эти поля задаются в текущем классе, а не генерируются.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type': 'password'})
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = ExtUser
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'password')
```